# OpenCV format knnMatch Descriptors

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, format, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 Python knnMatch where the query descriptors come directly from detectAndCompute and are formatted correctly, but the train descriptors will come from a list I made in a different program.

When I get the descriptors from my other program, they look like:

```
[array([ 14,  21, 234, 147, 215, 115, 190, 215,  94, 231,  31,  34, 200,
       124, 127, 104, 255, 123, 179, 147, 180, 240,  61, 226, 111,  95,
       159, 131, 151, 127, 253, 231], dtype=uint8), array([162, 150, 101, 219, 117, 151, 173, 113,  93,  29,  81,  23, 232,
        13,  60, 133, 221,   2, 147, 165, 242, 188, 120, 221,  39,  26,
       154, 194,  87, 140, 245, 252], dtype=uint8)]
```

That would be 2 descriptors.

How can I format these so I do not get the "OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats" error when matching these descriptors with those coming straight out of detectAndCompute? I have tried using np.asarray(list, np.float32) to no avail. If I do:

[[d for d in des] for des in list] with list as the train descriptors then the two lists will LOOK the same but I get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [[d for d in des] for des in list]
list = np.asarray(list, np.uint8)
for d in list:
    for x in d:
        x = x.astype(np.uint8)
```